# Attempting to open a user-specified file and process it, path is lost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on my first ASP.NET MVC 3 application and one thing I need to do is handle some data that is exported from someone else's system and turn around and import it, on user action, into the system and perform some error checking, etc. on it.

Here's how I have attempted to solve this issue:

I've got a view with a div:

```
<div>
   <span><b>Recipe Data:</b>
     <input type="file" name="uploadFile" />
     <input type="submit" value="Load" />
   </span>
</div>
```

and that allows me to choose a file and then submit it.  Then I've got a controller action that looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
{
   try
   {
      // attempt to read the file
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
      throw;
   }
}
```

So, when I'm using IE, I can examine the uploadFile parameter and it gives me a path like:

FileName:`c:\\Users\\Matt\\Desktop\\TestFiles\\AppleBerry.xml`

(which is exactly the full path to the file I picked)

But when I try the same thing in FireFox, that path is stripped off, so uploadFile.FileName is just AppleBerry.xml and the `XDocument.Load` tries to load it from:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\AppleBerry.xml`

So, I'm pretty sure that I'm going about this the wrong way and need some guidance.  I need to read in that XML file, preferably via `XDocument.Load()` and then do some checks and eventually push the records in that XML file into a DB table.  The only part I'm having issues with is this file path.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong but when you have received the file, does it really matter what the users path was? you in effect at the server side have an object without a path until you save it right?

Comment: string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../Uploads"), 
                                           Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.FileName));
            uploadFile.SaveAs(filePath);

Comment: @minus4 - yeah, I blew right past the idea that it was a client file path I guess because I'm sitting on my own dev box with it local.  It was odd though that IE worked and FF didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading the file directly from the request stream and don't rely on the `FileName` property because you haven't saved the file on the server yet so it won't find it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
{
    if (uploadFile != null && uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            // attempt to read the file
            var doc = XDocument.Load(uploadFile.InputStream);
            // TODO: do something with the XML document
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Make sure you do something more meaningful here
            // instead of rethrowing and erasing the stacktrace 
            throw;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // The user didn't upload any file => take respective actions
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Darin for your quick reply and for straightening me out on this!  I've still got a lot of learning to do with web-related development and I guess what threw me was that IE worked but FF didn't. I appreciate you Darin - I've learned a lot from reading your posts here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

The server does not have access to the client's file system so the original path is irrelevant. Furthermore the file is not saved onto the server file system, so you should be loading it from the `InputStream` property, as per Darin's answer.